# html canvas doesn't update in safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-canvas, gsap

I'm creating website on webflow and encounter problem with Safari. I have sequence animation made with gsap which you can see first when you are entering website. In every browser it works just fine. But in safari on ventura it doesn't scroll sequence. Sequence just freezes on one frame.

Here is my code. And [site](https://units-update.webflow.io/).

```
<style>
    canvas {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
  
  <canvas id="canvas-container" />
  
  <script async defer>
              const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-container");
              const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
              const frameCount = 36;
  
              /** const currentFrame = (index) =>
          `image-sequence/unt-dsktp_00000/unt-dsktp_${(index + 1).toString().padStart(5, "0")}.webp`;
              */
              let currentFrame = [];
  
              currentFrame[0] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888545be24d8b37e6b5cad_unt-dsktp_00000.webp";
              currentFrame[1] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888544f6215139a6c25fa3_unt-dsktp_00001.webp";
              currentFrame[2] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/648885459c6ab83eafdb8343_unt-dsktp_00002.webp";
              currentFrame[3] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/648885445c4f0ef369cfad19_unt-dsktp_00003.webp";
              currentFrame[4] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888545f953e3c4f766c44c_unt-dsktp_00004.webp";
              currentFrame[5] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/648885445c4f0ef369cfacd0_unt-dsktp_00005.webp";
  
  
              currentFrame[6] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888545e1cd9d72915fe5f6_unt-dsktp_00006.webp";
              currentFrame[7] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888545ec4bbea498e15a32_unt-dsktp_00007.webp";
              currentFrame[8] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888545f6215139a6c2600e_unt-dsktp_00008.webp";
              currentFrame[9] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/648885450a5d0637eb835ec0_unt-dsktp_00009.webp";
              currentFrame[10] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/6488854590f8a48b18951e96_unt-dsktp_00010.webp";
              currentFrame[11] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/648885459c6ab83eafdb8373_unt-dsktp_00011.webp";
  
  
              currentFrame[12] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/648885455cf942a94a1220e8_unt-dsktp_00012.webp";
              currentFrame[13] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/648885465cf942a94a122102_unt-dsktp_00013.webp";
              currentFrame[14] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/6488854690f8a48b18951ebf_unt-dsktp_00014.webp";
              currentFrame[15] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888546e64065dc221aa89c_unt-dsktp_00015.webp";
              currentFrame[16] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/648885466d313f2e4079fe7c_unt-dsktp_00016.webp";
              currentFrame[17] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888546e64065dc221aa954_unt-dsktp_00017.webp";
  
  
              currentFrame[18] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/648885469441ee76176a3a47_unt-dsktp_00018.webp";
              currentFrame[19] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/6488854626d7921913a41917_unt-dsktp_00019.webp";
              currentFrame[20] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888546d5b3bf8acb3c606d_unt-dsktp_00020.webp";
              currentFrame[21] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888546ee99490ab8b6004e_unt-dsktp_00021.webp";
              currentFrame[22] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888546ec4bbea498e15d2a_unt-dsktp_00022.webp";
              currentFrame[23] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/648885467e484493e2d26453_unt-dsktp_00023.webp";
  
  
              currentFrame[24] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/648885460a5d0637eb836043_unt-dsktp_00024.webp";
              currentFrame[25] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888547eb1c42246cbf5185_unt-dsktp_00025.webp";
              currentFrame[26] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/648885462d7041894aefa920_unt-dsktp_00026.webp";
              currentFrame[27] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888548d6b75626f3b76c57_unt-dsktp_00027.webp";
              currentFrame[28] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888549f6215139a6c26310_unt-dsktp_00028.webp";
              currentFrame[29] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888549bf3d4029e607aace_unt-dsktp_00029.webp";
  
  
              currentFrame[30] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888549ab1082779c70697f_unt-dsktp_00030.webp";
              currentFrame[31] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/648885499441ee76176a3cc3_unt-dsktp_00031.webp";
              currentFrame[32] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888549f953e3c4f766cba7_unt-dsktp_00032.webp";
              currentFrame[33] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/64888549a5a3d240d1575e27_unt-dsktp_00033.webp";
              currentFrame[34] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/6488854b9c6ab83eafdb8989_unt-dsktp_00034.webp";
              currentFrame[35] = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64776a1131688ea579106304/6488854bbe24d8b37e6b638a_unt-dsktp_00035.webp";
  
  
              const images = [];
              const sequence = {
                  frame: 0
              };
  
              for (let i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
                  const img = new Image();
                  img.src = currentFrame[i];
                  console.log(img);
                  images.push(img);
              }
  
              // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
              window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
              
              function resizeCanvas() {
                      canvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                      canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;                    
                      /**
                       * Your drawings need to be inside this function otherwise they will be reset when 
                       * you resize the browser window and the canvas goes will be cleared.
                       */
                       drawStuff(); 
              }
              resizeCanvas();
              
              
              function drawStuff() {
                  
                  gsap.to(sequence, {
                  frame: frameCount - 1,
                  snap: "frame",
                  ease: "power1.out",
                  scrollTrigger: {
                      trigger: "#canvas-container",
                      start: "top top",
                      end: "+=3500",
                      //markers: true,
                      //pin: true,
                      scrub: 0.1
                  },
                  onUpdate: render // use animation onUpdate instead of scrollTrigger's onUpdate
                  });
  
                  images[0].onload = render;
  
                  function render() {
  
                      canvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                      canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight; 
  
                      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
                      const iw     = images[sequence.frame].width;
                      const ih     = images[sequence.frame].height;
                      const cw     = canvas.width;
                      const ch     = canvas.height;
                      const f      = Math.max(cw/iw, ch/ih);
  
                      context.setTransform(
                          /*     scale x */ f,
                          /*      skew x */ 0,
                          /*      skew y */ 0,
                          /*     scale y */ f,
                          /* translate x */ (cw - f * iw) / 2,
                          /* translate y */ (ch - f * ih) / 2,
                      );
                      
                      
                      
                      context.drawImage(images[sequence.frame], 0, 0);
                  }
  
              }
  
          </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7dy8krzn/5/

I tried disable Lenis which I use for smooth scrolling, didn't help at all. Interesting that on mobile Safari it works, but on desktop no.

Comment: safari should r.i.p. and follow ie